# Ubuntu seemingly not detecting GPU?

Tags: drivers, display, gpu

Dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 but whenever I load up Ubuntu it is stuck in 1024x768. I try to change it in display but it's the only option. I figured it was an issue with the GPU drivers so I installed the latest and rebooted but still no luck. The video command gives me this:

```
 lshw -c video

*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcd7ffff memory:fcd80000-fcd9ffff
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong besides the drivers? They work on my Windows installation fine and when I'm in the GNU Kernel to select the OS it seems to be 1920x1080 but as soon as I go into Ubuntu it goes to 1024x768. My GPU is an RX 5700XT and like I said I installed the latest drivers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does dmesg | grep -i firm  list any missing firmware?